# What's the name of the box that appeared before "PCI Devices Listing" and "Verifying DMI Pool Data"?

Tags: boot, bios, history, post, terminology

Some 20 years ago computers used to come with a hardware setup that after BIOS POST but *before booting* from the disk or device, they showed a box made by ascii "box drawing characters" art, one like this in the upper half (half-visible):

[image: Verifying DMI Pool Data]

It says things like "pri. master disk" "pri. slave disk" "serial port(s)" "parallel port(s)" then follows  "pci devices listing" "bus" "dev" "fun" "vendor"...

Several, maybe 10 years back, this box started to disappear from the normal booting... Nowadays after the POST screen, only other things show up on a blank screen for a period of time, then they disappear, like network booting discovery, some device probing... whatever, back to the box! I would like to read more about this box, what system did it belong to, when did it disappear and why, what was it replaced with...

What is the name this box is used to be called?

Answer (score 2):

It's called the **Configuration Summary Screen** or **BIOS Configuration Summary Screen**

Reference (download it and reminisce):

http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/430TX/430TX_BIOS.pdf

You'll find it on page 1-4 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It was the BIOS showing you what settings/resources it's using for those devices.

I don't believe it ever had a name (that I've ever heard anyway :) ).

Newer BIOS don't do it.

Why?  Hard to say exactly, you will have to ask the BIOS authors. ;)

My guess would be that it's just not necessary anymore...  Many/most newer BIOSs tend to have a similar settings status screen within the BIOS itself, and the BIOSs got so fast that you'd never be able to see it anyway.

When?  Also hard to say.  It was phased out by different BIOS manufacturers at different times, and then the older BIOSs (with it) lived on in newer motherboards until the various motherboard manufacturers switched to the new versions (without it).

Lastly, "BIOS"s are being replaced by [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), so I wouldn't spend too much time contemplating old behaviours of what's become(ing) legacy tech.

Comment: thanks! my reasons for searching for this are historical interest, so it is no problem with me whether it is legacy tech or not. on an off note, I'm [not very confident](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3417033) in UEFI, [heard](http://www.lafkon.net/tc/) it is a drm/dmce/trusted computing thingy that can [lock you out](http://lwn.net/Articles/464394/) from your machine unless you give in to [vendor lock-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in)... Anyway... UEFI since it is not historical it is not my interest right now. it seems only manufacturers know the name then? looked std.

Comment: "fast boot" options and "logo" options vrses "post" options in both UEFI and BIOS , will also hide what little information there is now displayed.  You might be able to see a few items on different motherboards by adjusting settings of that type in there. These settings go by many different names, and the settings and options to show more, are not as available on an OEM manufactured computers, and more avialable on higher end motherboards and server motherboards.  EX: Disabling the Logo on some boards will show a post screen instead, even though it does not say that will happen.